# changing 2 random numbers in 30 times in number table using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, sudoku

In this code each time you open the html page two random numbers are generated and thier location in the matrix will be changed.
for example the random numbers are 2,8
in the main table 2 is in the matrix[0][1],matrix[1][7],matrix[2][4],matrix[3][0],matrix[4][6],matrix[5][3],matrix[6][8],matrix[3][0],matrix[7][5]
,matrix[8][2] .in the result table 8 is set in these location and 2 is set in the current locations of 8.
I want to repeat this, 30 times.

so far I have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var matrix = new Array();
matrix[0]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
matrix[1]=[4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3];
matrix[2]=[7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6];

matrix[3]=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1];
matrix[4]=[5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4];
matrix[5]=[8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];


matrix[6]=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2];
matrix[7]=[6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5];
matrix[8]=[9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

document.writeln('<table border="1">');
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
      {
    document.writeln('<tr>');
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
         document.writeln('<td>' + matrix[i][j] + '</td>');

    document.writeln('</tr>');
       }
document.writeln('</table>');


document.writeln('<table border="1">');
document.writeln("The random numbers are:");
document.writeln('<br>');
var r1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var r2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
document.writeln(r1);
document.writeln(r2);
document.writeln('<br>');
document.writeln("The result table is:");
        for(i=0; i<9; i++)
           {
              document.writeln('<tr>');
             for(j=0; j<9; j++)
                {
                 if(matrix[i][j]==r1)
                   {
                     matrix[i][j]=r2;
                     document.writeln('<td>' + matrix[i][j] + '</td>');
                    }
                 else if(matrix[i][j]!=r1 && matrix[i][j]!=r2)
                    document.writeln('<td>' + matrix[i][j] + '</td>');
                 else if(matrix[i][j]==r2)
                       {
                          matrix[i][j]=r1;  
                          document.writeln('<td>' + matrix[i][j] + '</td>');
                        }

                }

              document.writeln('</tr>');
           }

   document.writeln('</table>');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code slightly.

First, I'd make a method to print the table:

```
function printMatrix(var matrix)
{
   document.writeln('<table border="1">');
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
      {
    document.writeln('<tr>');
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
         document.writeln('<td>' + matrix[i][j] + '</td>');

    document.writeln('</tr>');
       }
document.writeln('</table>');
}
```

Then, I'd make a method for the swapping:

```
function sawpTwoNumbers(matrix)
{

document.writeln("The random numbers are:");
document.writeln('<br>');
var r1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var r2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
document.writeln(r1);
document.writeln(r2);
document.writeln('<br>');

// This is new code:

for(int i=0; i< matrix.length; i++){
    var r1Index = matrix[i].indexOf(r1);
    var r2Index = matrix[i].indexOf(r2);

    matrix[i][r1Index] = r2;
    matrix[i][r2Index] = r1;
}

}
```

Next, I'd put your code in the pageLoad method:

```
function pageLoad()
{
var matrix = new Array();
matrix[0]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
matrix[1]=[4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3];
matrix[2]=[7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6];

matrix[3]=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1];
matrix[4]=[5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4];
matrix[5]=[8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];


matrix[6]=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2];
matrix[7]=[6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5];
matrix[8]=[9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

printMatrix(matrix);

// This is new code:
// It will call the swap method and the print method 30 times.
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    swapTwoNumbers(matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
}
}
```

**Please Note:** I haven't tested this code. I don't guarantee that it works. I hope it'll give you a push in the right direction though.

Comment: :thanks for your answer, but I don't want 30 table output, I want this numbers 30 times swap in 1 table for example, 1 and 2 -- 2 and 3--

Comment: @blackrose ~ Then move the printMatrix call out of the for loop.

Comment: 3       2 1
1 5 4
1 7 2
1 3 5--------------> 1 3 5
Random numbers are: 2 and 3
5 and 1 ….
New table is :
2 3 5
5 1 4
5 7 3
5 2 1

Comment: @blackrose ~ What is the question there? You just copied and pasted what was in your question.

Comment: @blackrose ~ I never said it did. I actually said the exact opposite and that I don't guarantee it at all. This seems like a homework question. I outlined what I thought would help you without giving you the full answer. What I have posted should be enough to push you in the right direction.